# Change view of specific split view

Tags: windows, vba, excel

I'm looking to have my excel sheet with a split in it (vertically) ensuring a set of controls stay on the left of the screen for easy access. Currently Im using this code to select and move to a cell, based on a list of headings I have in the A column.

```
Option Explicit
Dim trimProcess() As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("A6:A1000")) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(trimProcess)
                If ActiveCell.Value = trimProcess(i) Then
                    Cells(4, 4 * (i + 1)).Select
                    Cells(4, 4 * (i + 1)).Activate
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This works fine for what I need, but it only works in the active split view IE if I click a cell in A in the left split, it moves the left split view. I want it so that the changes only the right view, but cant find the code to do so. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to mention trimProcess is set via a global method and is assumed to be populated when the cells are clicked.

Comment: Problem is solved, thanks